# Multilingual site in Smarty (config file or parse_ini_file)

Tags: php, smarty, multilingual

Now I am using parse_ini_file() to create multilingual site in a Smarty php file:

```
$lang_file=parse_ini_file("lang/". $_SESSION["lang_folder"] ."/lang_file.ini",true);
$this->tpl->assignByref("lang",$lang_file);
$this->tpl->display('page.tpl');
```

than in the page.tpl to call it:

```
{$lang.VARIABLE}
```

But I read that the parse_ini_file() is disabled some Hosting due to security reason so I want to figure out something to solve this.
I found the config file so in the top of the page.tpl should be placed this:

```
{config_load file='en_lang.conf'} {* depending on current language stored in session *}
```

Is it good or there is something easy and general method?

Comment: There are no security issues in `parse_ini_file` and never have been.  If you encounter users of yours that are using hosts that disable it, you can safely tell the user that their host is incompetent for listening to unsubstantiated rumor and basing their own security practices on copy/paste.

Comment: ok, I see! But are there any difference between the two methods (e.g. speed)?

Comment: Benchmark it and find out.  I imagine that `parse_ini_file` may be a bit faster, but that's mainly because I'm biased against Smarty.